# qsharp and python: remove 'preparing qsharp environment' message from console

Tags: python, python-3.6, q#

I started tutorial of qsharp and i wrote my first qsharp and python (host) codes. But when i run qsharp codes in console, gets some messages in console.

[image: qsharp-messgaes]

I want console shows only qsharp outputs.

Comment: '1' (in image) is my codes output.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: This looks like a possible bug in IQ#, used internally by Python interoperability. Would you be willing to share this as a bug report to https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/, along with the version of Python and IQ# that you're using in this example? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: Just a quick note that this should be fixed with the next IQ# release (later this month). More details in https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/251 (which I believe is the issue you just filed - thank you!).

Answer (score 0):

Vscode / Anaconda gives similar output. The last line is what i added to print output.

Microsoft.Quantum.Runtime.Core, Version=0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40866b40fd95c7f5
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp.Jupyter, Version=0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40866b40fd95c7f5
Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp.AzureClient, Version=0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40866b40fd95c7f5
Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.QCTraceSimulatorRuntime, Version=0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40866b40fd95c7f5
Microsoft.Quantum.Standard, Version=0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40866b40fd95c7f5
Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Common, Version=0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40866b40fd95c7f5
Preparing Q# environment...
The random number generated is 36